# Unable to run process with arguments

Tags: python, vb.net, process.start

### Program Logic

Trying to run python script using Process.Start() with agrument. I'm trying to automate a script using GUI where for each list of arguments, a new python command is generated and run.

---

### Problem

The python process does not start. CMD window displays for very short time and closes. Basically the python script doesn't run.

*Note*: The python script is running properly when run manually through cmd. Also the 2nd tried code (below) runs when there is isn't any arguments, ie, when only the python script is called without arguments.

So, giving there is an error somewhere when I try to pass arguments and call the script.

### Tried Solutions

**Code: 1st Try**

```
For Each common_dir In common_dirs
     ' command for starting python script
     Dim command As String = utils.pyModDir & "Sys_File_Lister.py" & " " & "-d" & " " & "'" & common_dir & "'"
     Try
          'MsgBox(utils.python_Path)
          Process.Start(utils.python_Path, command).WaitForExit()
          Catch ex As Exception
               MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
     End Try
Next
```

**Code: 2nd Try**

```
Using proc As New Process()
     ' set the filename for process
     proc.StartInfo.FileName = utils.python_Path
     ' set the arguments for process
     proc.StartInfo.Arguments = """" & command & """"
     MsgBox(proc.StartInfo.Arguments.ToString)
     Try
          ' start the process
          proc.Start()
          ' wait for the process to complete
          proc.WaitForExit()
          ' if error
     Catch ex As Exception
          MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
End Using
```

**Code: 3rd Try**

This time, instead of calling the python script using python directly, I called *cmd.exe* in *StartInfo.FileName* and called everything else in *StartInfo.Arguments* as suggested.

This time it results in file not found error message.

This is the formed string passed in Arguments for CMD: [image: Screenshot: Argument String]

From the above command, also tried removing the quotes from python path and keeping it for the script path, but same error.

```
Using proc As New Process()
    ' set the filename for process
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe /K "
    ' set the arguments for process
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = """" & command & """"
    MsgBox(proc.StartInfo.Arguments.ToString)
    Try
        ' start the process
        proc.Start()
        ' wait for the process to complete
        proc.WaitForExit()
        ' if error
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Using
```

**Help** : Any help is appeciated!

Comment: Try to use for _ProcessStartInfo.FileName_ property the string _cmd.exe_ then put everything in the _Arguments_ property but prefix everything with _/K_ . This should leave the console open with any error message displayed

Comment: Thanks for help, but this results in an error (updated post with details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there seems to be an issue only when passing the python script with arguments, one quick remedy was to add the arguments in a text file and read it on python script load..

It worked, but it doesn't solve the current problem. However, this is a secondary solution that worked in my case here. Hope this helps someone. Below are python commands used. I removed argument parser from python script and instead of *-d arg* I read the argument from file like this:

```
# check the list_from configuration
list_conf_path = "list_from.txt"
list_conf = ""
if isfile(list_conf_path):
    with open(list_conf_path, 'r') as f:
        list_conf = f.readline()
list_conf = list_conf.replace('"', '')
print(list_conf)

# start the main function
if list_conf != "":
    init(list_conf)
else:
    init("C:\\")
```

Again, not an exact solution, but secondary one.